# Whats the brief factual difference between Kubernetes, Helm and Rancher (and others)

Tags: docker, kubernetes, devops, kubernetes-helm, rancher

As a new starter in the world of DevOps, I've tried to find a one-pager that explains side by side what each of the following technologies do best and how they are orchestrated together in typical deployment scenario.

Its all a bit overwhelming coming in cold.

Seems like there's a technology for every single step of the deployment. Have some been superseded by others? Are the differentiated in the granularity of the artifact?

No opinions please of which is better, just resources of hey they are used together.

- Docker
- Kubernetes
- Helm
- Terraform
- Rancher

Comment: Sorry guys, my question was closed because it wasn't worded properly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Docker** is the de facto standard for building containers and running them in various environments.

**Kubernetes** is a complex framework for orchestrating containers.

**Helm** is a component of Kubernetes, a package manager for running apps on Kubernetes.

(**Rancher** is a framework for managing and orchestrating containers. It could also manage Kubernetes clusters)

A typical scenario 'devops' scenario would involve builiding **Docker** images from source, and running them in A **kubernetes** cluster in production, as described in a **Helm** chart. The underlying infrastructure for Kubernetes could be deployed with **Terraform**.

Comment: And terraform would be a tool/framework used to define / prepare the infrastructure prior to deployment of containers (roughly)

Comment: And Tiller is the server side of the Helm v2 which is removed in Helm v3

Comment: So it sounds like Rancher is an opinionated "better" way to orchestrate containers compared to how Kubernetes does it?

Comment: Rancher evolved over the years to do different things. They even offer their own distribution of K8s now.  As a beginner, I would revisit Rancher at a later stage and first focus on the core stack of docker/K8s  and underlying cloud services.

Comment: Thanks guys for your answers before the mods killed this question.  Not sure how to ask a question these days!

Comment: There is also devops.stackexchange.com for these broad topics.